# Django template ifequal statement always true

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates

Hi I am building a simple blog using Python/Django. In my index.html file, I am trying to show archived posts when a button containing a month is clicked. At the moment, I am just trying to get the id of every post made in that month into a javascript array. For some reason though,it always returns true!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPosts(month)
{
var posts_in_month=[];
{% for post in all_posts %}
var match = {{ post.pub_date.month }}
    {% ifequal match month %}
      posts_in_month.push({{ post.id }})
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
}
</script>
```

I then go on to have a switch statement where I show the contents of the array depending on the month clicked. The code definitely works, when I call an alert(month) it shows up correctly, and when I call alert({{ post.pub_date.month }}) it shows up fine as well. These are usually not the same though, why is it always evaluating the ifequal to true?

Comment: You're mixing django varibales with javascrip variables, `match` and `month` aren't ind django scope, and you can't use `ifequal`.

Comment: You're right. I see what I did. The solution was to use an if statement using js instead of the template tags.

 

    if(match==month)
    {
    posts_in_month.push({{ post.id }})
    }

I'm pretty new to Javascript as well (a total noob to be honest) so I didn't see what was wrong.

Comment: See you generated HTML code, it cant helps.

Comment: @user2676680 Please, don't do that. Mixing and matching Django template language and javascript will lead you down a path of problems. Instead of coupling your javascript to your django template you should try to decouple.

Comment: Good to know. I will keep that in mind and avoid this pitfall in the future. Thanks.

Comment: normaly, you should made a ajax request to get the "all_posts",then,it`s all javascript ,to fullfill this ,define a view return data in json

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Javascript variable in python and use it as python's variable.

Replace the `match` with actual value:

```
{% ifequal post.pub_date.month month %}
  posts_in_month.push({{ post.id }})
{% endifequal %}
```